# Js object and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to treat a javascript object as jQuery object in a certain way,
like assign to it jQuery functionality but avoid working with the DOM tree of the browser for more efficiency and when appended as DOM object this functionality is triggered?

If possible please provide some good examples,

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

> At present, the only operations supported on plain JavaScript objects
>   wrapped in jQuery are: .data(),.prop(),.bind(), .unbind(),.trigger()
>   and .triggerHandler(). The use of .data() (or any method requiring
>   .data()) on a plain object will result in a new property on the object
>   called jQuery{randomNumber} (eg. jQuery123456789).

You can wrap a plain object in a jQuery object and use those functions.

Also from the same page:

```
// define a plain object
var foo = {foo:'bar', hello:'world'};

// wrap this with jQuery
var $foo = $(foo);

// test accessing property values
var test1 = $foo.prop('foo'); // bar

// test setting property values
$foo.prop('foo', 'foobar');
var test2 = $foo.prop('foo'); // foobar

// test using .data() as summarized above
$foo.data('keyName', 'someValue');
console.log($foo); // will now contain a jQuery{randomNumber} property

// test binding an event name and triggering
$foo.bind('eventName', function (){
        console.log('eventName was called');
});

$foo.trigger('eventName'); // logs 'eventName was called'
```